# MarkLogic TDE, security database failure after upgrade rollback

Tags: nosql, marklogic

We have a Dev database for TDE. It was upgraded from 10.0-4 to 10.0-5. Due to the performance degradation, we rollback to 10.0-4. The rollback was successful and the database is running fine until I inserted TDE template.

```
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";
 
let $vendors :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>vendor</context>
+++++++++++++++++++++
</template>
 
return tde:template-insert("/vendors.xml", $vendors);
```

It throws error:

```
[1.0-ml] TDE-ROLLINGUPGRADE: (err:FOER0000) Cannot add a TDE template during rolling upgrade: /vendors.xml
Stack Trace
In /MarkLogic/tde.xqy on line 42
In tde:template-insert("/vendors.xml", <template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde"><context>vendor</context>...</template>, (<sec:permission...), ())
```

The Admin console doesn’t look normal:

Local Cluster  --  Local Cluster Configuration

Effective Version   10000500, cluster is partially upgraded

ErrorLog records below errors and no other errors reported:

```
Notice: Skipping reindex of forest Schemas until security database is upgraded old version=100005 new version=100004…
```

We uninstall, reinstall MarkLogic but still the TDE/system can’t function. We don’t have the database backup. It is very difficult to reload all the documents and modules if we start from scratch. Can someone help to recover the system?

As requested, I posted below versioning after the upgrade rollback:

clusters.xml:

```
  <security-version>100004</security-version>
  <effective-version>10000400</effective-version>
```

clusters_1.xml, clusters_2.xml:

```
  <security-version>100004</security-version>
  <effective-version>10000500</effective-version>
```

Comment: You need to recover the MarkLogic `clusters##.xml` to bring the engine consistent. In your case, effective db and the security version needs to be compatible.  Just an analogy, if any of the control files in Oracle cluster is inconsistent state, an Oracle instance simply can’t start. If all of the Oracle control files are lost/corrupted and no backup, new control file (binary file) can be manually recreated using SQL.

Comment: Considering your ML system is constrained by an incompatible security version number messed up in the XML file; you don’t have any ML backup, can you manually synchronise the versions across all the `clusters##.xml` => `<security-version>100004</security-version>  <effective-version>10000400</effective-version>`?  Suggest you clean shutdown and backup the `/Data` before making any change.

Comment: Fiona:  We experiment different workarounds without success. At the moment, only your workaround has reverted the system and TDE to the normal state.  Should you post the comments as Answer, I will accept it.  We much appreciate your help!